# Trouble installing AD-HOC distribution through safari

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, provisioning

I've spent about 4 hours trying to get adhoc installation via safari working.
My app works fine in the simulator and I even had it working fine on my device in debug.
I've created an adhoc distribution profile with UDID's and created an archive using the adhoc provisioning.
I created an ipa using 'Save for Enterprise Distribution' and filled the details in with location of the ipa etc..
Uploaded to web space with a basic html with the link.

Now, when I click the link on my iPhone it downloads the app however it fails to install.
This is the console log

```
    Feb 20 00:49:59 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/com.venderbase.ibetandwin-0A53F66A-32AF-4460-BCA6-27D20BD1F349'
Feb 20 00:49:59 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/com.venderbase.ibetandwin-BDA582E5-CAF2-4846-AA9A-81FF96E10A4F'
Feb 20 00:49:59 unknown installd[121] <Error>: 00583000 extract_package: Could not extract archive
Feb 20 00:49:59 unknown installd[121] <Error>: 00583000 stage_package: Could not extract /var/tmp/install_staging.fgTWMV/foo.zip to /var/tmp/install_staging.fgTWMV/foo_extracted
Feb 20 00:49:59 unknown installd[121] <Error>: 00583000 MobileInstallationInstall: Could not stage the package
Feb 20 00:49:59 unknown com.apple.itunesstored[130] <Notice>: MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Feb 20 00:49:59 unknown installd[121] <Error>: 00583000 handle_install: API failed
Feb 20 00:49:59 unknown installd[121] <Error>: 00583000 send_message: failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003
Feb 20 00:49:59 unknown installd[121] <Error>: 00583000 send_error: Could not send error response to client
```

I am stuck with the partially installed app icon on my iPhone. I have tried syncing with iTunes to remove it and restarting but it won't go.

How can I get this to a) install or b) delete?

Thanks

Comment: To get it to delete, you may try the standard way to remove apps by holding down on the icon until they start wiggling and press the X. It likely won't not delete the first time, and you may need to do it twice in a row.

Comment: The x disappears but the icon remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that my ipa was fine and signed correctly. The problem was the stuck partial installs of previous iPad's that mustn't have been built properly.
I used Jacobs idea of keep pressing the x to get rid of them. I had to keep holding icon, pressing x, press home, hold icon, press x etc... About 5 times and it eventually disappeared.
Then my ipa installed fine.

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue. Just deleting the app from springboard didn't work, but deleting it and then rebooting the device worked fine.

Comment: Took me 3 times but sure enough it disappeared. Crazy town.

Answer (score 2):

I've had great success using Beta Builder: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/betabuilder-for-ios-apps/id415348946?mt=12 It's $2, and saves a lot of hassle.

Still, the distribution provisioning profiles occasionally give me trouble when I've just added a device. One thing that seems to help is to delete the provisioning profile from XCode, and Quit XCode altogether... Launch XCode and add the profile... Archive and distribute. Then, open the IPA file in BetaBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to change the bundle version (increment it) which convinces the device that something has been updated. That trick worked for me in a similar situation!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience with the Springboard[15] problem indicated above when attempting to uninstall a failed over the air (OTA) installation from the iPad.  Multiple attempts to uninstall finally removed the app.

Also experienced a related  Springboard[51] error during failed OTA ad-hoc installations.  Both have to do with not being able to find a resource on a given path.

I ultimately discovered that the icon files were somehow not properly associated with the app resulting in a invalid manifest.  Removing the icons then adding them back in and re-archiving, building a new distribution and uploading the .ipa and .plist to the website solved the problem.